# I am not able to create a unreal engine 4.27.1 c++ project

Tags: unreal-engine4

whenever i create a C++ project in Unreal Engine4, it throws me this error:Activation context generation failed for "E:\Personal\Applications\UE\UE_4.27\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool.exe".Error in manifest or policy file "E:\Personal\Applications\UE\UE_4.27\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool.exe.Config" on line 0. Invalid Xml syntax. I have tried many solutions from the inter net but it is not working, pleace can anybody help me.

Comment: What is the contents of `UnrealBuildTool.exe.Config`?

Comment: Not a C++ question. Random guess: that file got corrupted and does not contain XML?